# How to disable buffering in nodejs sockets/streams?

Tags: node.js, http, stream, request, buffer

I'm trying to disable the default buffering mechanisms present in "http" and/or "request" modules in order to have a real-time piped stream. A simple representation of what I want to achieve is:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, resp){
    let newReq = request("<url>");
    req.pipe(newReq);
    newReq.pipe(resp);
    req.connection.setNoDelay(true);
    resp.connection.setNoDelay(true);
}
```

As you can see I've tried `setNoDelay(true)` but it still buffers and there is delay in the reply stream.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: .pipe() will set up a stream that must buffer as part of the node backpressure system. setNoDelay is simply a way to disable parts of TCP to make the OS send your messages... slightly faster.

So I don't think you can disable the buffer, but someone might come along with some hacky method